# How to use Django-filters with large data?

Tags: django, django-filter, django-filters

I am using Django-filter with django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter. I am facing the issue that the website is very slow if I have large data in Suburb table.

```
class PDetailFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
class Meta:
    model = PDetail
    fields = {
        # 'code': ['icontains'],
        # 'bu_name': ['icontains'],
        # 'bc_effect_date' : ['year__gt', 'year__lt', ],
    }

# Filter by Suburb
suburb = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(label="Suburb", queryset=Suburb.objects.all())
```

Comment: What is slow exactly? Show us the view or the form that takes time loading. Maybe you need to nest the data. For example if you're filtering on suburbs, and you already know a city, you could filter on just the suburbs in that city. Try not to load all data at once in your User interface, it's also easier for the user if they have just a small list to select from.

Comment: @dirkgroten: It is very slow. I only have filter by suburb. I know that I should not load all data to user interface but I dont know how to do with Django-filter

Answer (score 0):

Finially, I found the answer.
I am using django-autocomplete-light. You could check a tutorial here: https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html

Here is some source code
In View.py file:

```
class SuburbAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2ListView):
def get_list(self):
    # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
    # if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
    #     return Suburb.objects.none()

    qs = Suburb.objects.all()
    if self.q:
        qs = qs.filter(suburb__istartswith=self.q)
    return qs
```

In Filters.py

```
# Filter by Suburb
suburb = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
label="Suburb",
queryset=Suburb.objects.all(), 
widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
    url='backend:suburb-autocomplete',
    attrs={
            # Set some placeholder
            'data-placeholder': 'Suburb ...',
            # Only trigger autocompletion after 2 characters have been typed
            'data-minimum-input-length': 2,
            'style': 'height:34px !important;'
        },
    )
)
```